# How do i make my vim to look like this

Tags: vim

[image: Vim Screenshot]
How do i get the file manager in leftside in my vim configuration,and line numbers in cli mode.

Comment: File manager in the image is NERD Tree and github link is https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree which the file system explorer for the Vim editor for exact configuration like above image you can check spacevim - https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim

Answer (score 1):

Those are customizations on vim.rc There are many file managers you can get [Vaffle](https://github.com/cocopon/vaffle.vim)

The line numbers can be enabled with the command:

set nu!

To use it you must press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go to command mode. And then:

```
:set nu!
```